# how do i update mulitple rows with dynamic data?

Tags: sqlite

I am using SQLite to update mulipte rows, but it does not work.

`item` table to keep the item data

```
item_ID Qty
-       -
1      10
2      10
3      10
```

`user_basket` table to keep users' basket data

```
user_ID item_ID  Bask_Qty 
-        -       - 
1        1       5
1        2       1
2        1       1
```

I used command like:

```
UPDATE item 
SET Qty = 
(SELECT Qty-Bask_Qty FROM user_basket 
INNER JOIN item ON item.item_ID = user_basket.item_ID) 
WHERE item_ID IN (SELECT item_ID FROM user_basket WHERE user_ID = 1);
```

After the command, I should expect `item` table be like that:

```
item_ID Qty
-       -
1      5
2      9
3      10
```

but instead, I got:

```
item_ID Qty
-       -
1      5
2      5
3      10
```

apparently, it used the same value to update all the rows.

Comment: Create a https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27 and update your post with the url

Comment: You must aggregate backets by the items (and maybe filter by user_id) then use aggregated total value for updating.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE item 
SET Qty = Qty -
(SELECT sum(Bask_Qty) FROM user_basket 
 Where item.item_ID = user_basket.item_ID and user_basket.user_ID = 1);
```

This would update all items, though you may not notice it ( minus zero! ).
Better add your

```
WHERE item_ID IN (SELECT item_ID FROM user_basket WHERE user_ID = 1);
```